# Get max value from unsorted array list using JSR223 PostProcessor

Tags: jmeter

Please check the image :

[image]

Got the list of array
deviceSerialNo_id = "162,805,806,818,797,813,827,798,819,829,817,830,832,833,834,835"

Now want to extract the max value from it

Answer (score 0):

You can get the max number using java stream:

```
int max = Arrays.asList(vars.get("deviceSerialNo_id").split(",")).stream()
  .map(String::trim).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).max().get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Groovy code you can use [Collections.max()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection)) function like:

```
Collections.max(vars.get('deviceSerialNo_id').replaceAll('\"','').split(',').collect {it as int})
```

However a better idea would be switching to [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide/) which provides [max() function](https://jmespath.org/proposals/functions.html#max) out of the box

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Collections;
idlistall = vars.get("deviceSerialNo_id_ALL");
idlistall = idlistall.replace("[","");
idlistall = idlistall.replace("]","");
List<String> idlist = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(idlistall.split(",")));
def max_value = Collections.max(idlist);
vars.put("deviceSerialNo_id_max",max_value);
log.info(max_value);
```